# WebStorm: use .prettierrc configurations for formatting

Tags: formatting, webstorm, prettier

In WebStorm I want to use my custom configuration from `.prettierrc` file for code formatting.

It can change by the time I want to sync.

For example pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> let my WebStorm formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your `.prettierrc` in the project root and set up Prettier as the [default formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter) - this should do the thing

Comment: thank you its helps me , but how i can change default directory root to for example  ```configs/.prettierrc```

Comment: the Prettier plugin resolves the configuration files according to the logic described in https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html: configuration file is resolved starting from the location of the file being formatted, and searching up the file tree until a config file is found. Sibling folders won't be traversed, so `configs/.prettierrc` won't work

Comment: I don't like Visual Studio Code but in VSCode its possible so it is what it is :)
I duplicate my file and add it to .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to use configuration from other directory than root (let's say `configs/.prettierrc`), you can do this:

1. In `configs/.prettierrc` change source config to `.cjs` file:

```
/** @type {import('prettier').Config} */
module.exports = {
    // ... your rules
};
```

2. In root directory create another `.prettierrc.cjs` file and export source config from there:

```
module.exports = require("./configs/.prettierrc.cjs");
```

Restart IDE and that should do the trick.